# Errors in attrs.xml

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

All of sudden I come across a problem. It may be silly to ask but posting this because I have no idea what to do in such cases.

I am not aware if its an error or not.

Actually, I am getting problem in **attrs.xml** and whenever I am trying to save the project console prompt with following errors. I don't know where this file is located as in res>values I only find **styles.xml**, **dimens.xml**, and **strings.xml** but no **attrs.xml**. Secondly, as soon as I encountered with this problem R.java file is also not getting created.

Devs, just help me in resolving this and let me know if any other file you need to locate the error.

**Errors are :**

```
[2014-03-09 19:13:31 - Pocket Weather] E:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:32: error: Attribute "windowActionBar" has already been defined
[2014-03-09 19:13:31 - Pocket Weather] E:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:33: error: Attribute "windowActionBarOverlay" has already been defined
[2014-03-09 19:13:31 - Pocket Weather] E:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:34: error: Attribute "windowSplitActionBar" has already been defined
[2014-03-09 19:13:31 - Pocket Weather] E:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:45: error: Attribute "actionBarTabStyle" has already been defined
[2014-03-09 19:13:31 - Pocket Weather] E:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:46: error: Attribute "actionBarTabBarStyle" has already been defined
[2014-03-09 19:13:31 - Pocket Weather] E:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:47: error: Attribute "actionBarTabTextStyle" has already been defined
[2014-03-09 19:13:31 - Pocket Weather] E:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:48: error: Attribute "actionOverflowButtonStyle" has already been defined
[2014-03-09 19:13:31 - Pocket Weather] E:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:50: error: Attribute "actionBarStyle" has already been defined
[2014-03-09 19:13:31 - Pocket Weather] E:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:58: error: Attribute "actionBarSplitStyle" has already been defined
[2014-03-09 19:13:31 - Pocket Weather] E:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:66: error: Attribute "actionBarWidgetTheme" has already been defined
[2014-03-09 19:13:31 - Pocket Weather] E:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:69: error: Attribute "actionBarSize" has already been defined
[2014-03-09 19:13:31 - Pocket Weather] E:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:71: error: Attribute "actionBarDivider" has already been defined
[2014-03-09 19:13:31 - Pocket Weather] E:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:73: error: Attribute "actionBarItemBackground" has already been defined
[2014-03-09 19:13:31 - Pocket Weather] E:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:76: error: Attribute "actionMenuTextAppearance" has already been defined
[2014-03-09 19:13:31 - Pocket Weather] E:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:78: error: Attribute "actionMenuTextColor" has already been defined
[2014-03-09 19:13:31 - Pocket Weather] E:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:80: error: Attribute "homeAsUpIndicator" has already been defined
[2014-03-09 19:13:31 - Pocket Weather] E:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:82: error: Attribute "textAppearanceLargePopupMenu" has already been defined
```

Comment: It's seems like problem about  your `appcompat_v7 library` so remove it from project and add it again and clean and built your project

Comment: How to do that? @SimplePlan

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I removed the the library appcompat_v7 which is used for using Action Bar for lower version that API 11.

Follow the step:

Right click on your project > properties > select "Android"

Under "Library", remove the library you want.

It maybe some libraries include other libraries so you couldn't remove it from where you have tried.

Comment: @Saagy +1 up for your answer. Might be helpful to others.

Comment: @SimplePlan :). Worked because of your suggestion and help.